# WxWidgets dynamic event handler resize

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

In WxWidgets when using a Dynamic event table versus a static one, with capturing a resize event.
with a static table I use

```
EVT_SIZE(MyFrame::OnSize)
```

and for reference for a menu item I use

```
EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, MyFrame::OnAbout)
//for the dynamic
frame->Connect( wxID_ABOUT,
    wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED,
    wxCommandEventHandler(MyFrame::OnAbout) );
```

ok so with the menu in the dynamic setup wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED is used
while in the static setup I use EVT_MENU. so my question is what do I use instead of EVT_SIZE?
I'm also wondering what the differance is between the two EVT_MENU and wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED. One more what type of thing are they in c++? enums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is what do I use instead of EVT_SIZE?

```
wxEVT_SIZE
```

Answer (score 1):

In wxWidgets 3.0, you can, and should, use `wxEVT_MENU` instead of `wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED` too as all the event type constants have been renamed to the same names as are used by the macros, for consistency (the old names still exist for compatibility and there is no real harm in using them, but they're long and unwieldy, so why bother).

As for the type, the `wxEVT_XXX` themselves are just `int`s, but there are also matching specializations of `wxEventTypeTag<>` template for them, so you can't just define your own ones, see [wxDECLARE_EVENT()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#ga767b12d37f7370bc5f6b3d62340f3ef8) and [wxDEFINE_EVENT()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#ga09ec1d095bee3085c1cb31459b46bc00) macros for the proper way to do it.